# Executing script written inside the div when the div dynamically loads on to the page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a div which looks like

```
<div>
//Useful content
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function(){
           //some useful code
        }
   </script>
</div>
```

Now am getting this div as a response of an Ajax call and appending that into body. Now when the gets appended to body, the function inside the script tag should get executed. But not.. what is the problem here?

Comment: What calls the function? What errors are you getting?

Comment: jQuery?  If I recall correctly, scripts added to the DOM after load complete aren't automatically run.  But jQuery will run 'em for you if you use that for your AJAX / DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `document.createElement("script");` if you need to insert some script dynamically. This is recommended approach.

Anyway, following code is working just fine for me:

```
var str = "<script>alert('Hi!');</scr"+"ipt>";
$('#container').append($(str)[0]);
```

Make sure you escape you script properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not executing because it is not being called.

You should use a self-executing function that will just run as soon as it's loaded:

```
(function() {
    alert('hello world!');
})();
```